# Problems with AllcountJS Getting Started Guide

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, failed-installation

I have a problem with the installation of the framework AllcountJS.

I followed everything showed as standard:
https://allcountjs.com/docs/getting-started

But when I start, everything stops on

```
MacBook-Pro:vdgcrm vdg$ allcountjs run
Using db url: mongodb://localhost:27017/vdgcrm
{ Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vdg/vdgcrm/node_modules/bson/ext/index.js:15:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
Failed to fetch "app-config". Trying to use as regular directory.
```

Please help to solve this problem, since it is very necessary for my studies in university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says AllcountJS can't find `bson` module via npm system. The easiest way to fix that is changing the `require` path at `index.js` file.

So, go to `node_modules/bson/ext/index.js` and change all the lines:

```
bson = require('../Release/bson');
```

to

```
bson = require('../browser_build/bson');
```

Also, remember that as per official docs, MongoDB should be running in order to run this example. Then, make sure you have it [properly installed and running](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/).